# Opentelemetry with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, monitoring, open-telemetry

I wanna integrate open telemetry to my node.js and I have a few questions about this project.

I am particularly interested in metrics and tracing Is it worth it to go for open telemetry or just get a Prometheus exporter and Zipkin/jaeger?

Also, I am a little bit confused about metrics in open telemetry for js. There arent any default basic metrics that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metrics in OpenTelemetry are currently undergoing continued development and refinement, so they aren't necessarily available for each language yet (see [this tag in the OpenTelemetry JS repo](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Afeature-request) for an example of metric instruments that aren't up to date yet with spec), but once they are, I'd expect for metrics to be added to the existing node/web instrumentation packages.

That said, I would still advise you to try out OpenTelemetry for traces at this point, as it's pretty stable for tracing. You can use a Prometheus client to export metrics separately, and once OpenTelemetry metrics are fully supported in the JS library, switch over to that.